# Show Different Classes in Tree View Structure for Documentation

Tags: class, documentation-generation

I want to know if there is such tool that can show my classes hierarchy in a tree, e.g.

```
public Class ClassA
{
ClassB variableb;
ClassC variableC; 
}
```

so, it shows me something like

ClassA

- ClassB
- ClassC

I have shown in bullted format, I just want that this kind of things be shown in tree view, is there any tool which can help me create this tree of classes ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution in the form of class Diagram, don't why I didnt think of them at first place. :)